# How do I use Client in a cog in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to give my bot a status inside my 'on_ready.py' cog. So when it comes online the status switches to idle and a command prefix shows in the 'playing' part of the bot's profile.

This is my current code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is online.')
```

and I'm trying to implement this:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await client.change presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('f.'))
        print('Bot is online.')
```

I'm new to this so any help is appreciated.

edit: this is the code for the full cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class OnReady(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await client.change presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('using f.'))
        print('Bot is online.')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(OnReady(client))
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to include your full code? At the very least, the full cog code. You should have something like `self.bot` as part of your cog. You should use this instead of `client`, so `self.bot.change_pressence`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `self.client` when you create the `OnReady` class, so use this instead of `self.bot`. You also don't need to pass anything to the `on_ready` event, so it becomes `async def on_ready(self):`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class OnReady(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('using f.'))
        print('Bot is online.')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(OnReady(client))
```